# List files in Google Cloud Storage throws: AccessDeniedException: 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

Good day,

I am new to GCS and trying to access a partner's bucket using CLI. I have installed gsutil using documentation provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#install) (NOTE: I'm using macOS) and now I am trying to list files within a bucket. Access id key and secret have been provided which I use them to create a config file using:

```
gsutil config -a
```

which outputs:

```
Boto config file "/path/to/.boto" created. If you need to
use a proxy to access the Internet please see the instructions in that
file.
```

However, when I use the following command to list files within a bucket:

```
gsutil ls gs://bucket-name
```

It says:

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 myemail@domain.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

I think it's probably because of a sign in that I did as part of initializing google cloud using:

```
gcloud init
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to force `ls` command to use stored credentials instead of my email address and login that I did earlier. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check if you are logged in as a user who has permision to the files/bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what fixed the issue for me on my laptop. I ran this first:

```
gcloud config set pass_credentials_to_gsutil false
```

And then the `ls` command would work just fine. What is strange to me is that adding `/` to the original `ls` command that I posted fixed the issue on another instance:

```
gsutil ls gs://bucket-name/
```

Answer (score 0):

hello you can try with npm

try npm i @google-cloud/storage

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there is a way to force ls command to use stored credentials instead of my email address and login that I did earlier

1. Create a service account with necessary permission (ex Storage Admin `roles/storage.admin`)
2. Run `gsutil config -e` and insert the full path to your private key file
3. Run the `gsutil ls` command, and gsutil will use the service account credentials.

[config - Obtain credentials and create configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config)